# Truncating a flat file content in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want my SSIS package to read a flat file and truncate the contents after a specific symbol(lets say -->). Could anyone please suggest any steps for this?

Comment: if the symbol occurs once then a possiblilly is to use a script transform to switch to an ignored output when it encounters the flag. dump the required output to a new file. use a file task to replace the old file. If the symbol is repeated on rows you can filter out with either a query or conditional split.

Comment: In order to do that SSIS will need to parse every character or line - SSIS is not an efficient tool for that.

Comment: Help me understand this. Are you looking for just something to put an end of file marker whenever it encounters the specified symbol or do you mean read data, as in a flat file source component, and stop sending data once the specified symbol is encountered **and** also truncate the source file from that point forward?